# Swift 3 - iterate over generic collection

Tags: swift3, iterator, sequence

I have struct `Queue<T>` that is based on a `LinkedList<T>()` I want to be able to iterate over the element in the queue and do something with them.

After doing some digging, I believe I have to inherit from `Sequence` and do something like this:

```
extension Sequence {
    public func makeIterator() -> CountableRange<T>.Iterator {
        return (0..<self).makeIterator()
    }
}
```

and after I can have a function in my Queue class something like:

```
func iter(q: T) -> T? {
        for i in q {
        }
    }
```

except the extension throws `Use of undeclared type 'T'` and the for loop a `Type 'T' does not conform to protocol 'Sequence'`

I am fairly new to Swift and I understand what I have to do I just don't know how to do it and find most explanations quite confusing. Could someone point me in the right direction?

```
import Foundation

public struct Queue<T> : Sequence{

    fileprivate var list = LinkedList<T>()

    public var queueCount : Int {
        return list.getCount()
    }

    public var isEmpty: Bool {
        return list.isEmpty
    }

    public mutating func enqueue(_ element: T) {
        list.append(value: element)
    }


    public mutating func dequeue() -> T? {
        guard !list.isEmpty, let element = list.first else { return nil }

        list.remove(node: element)

        return element.value
    }


    public func peek() -> T? {
        return list.first?.value
    }

    func iter(q: T) -> T? {
        for i in q {
        }
    }

}

extension Queue: CustomStringConvertible {
    // 2
    public var description: String {
        // 3
        return list.description
    }
}

extension Sequence {
    public func makeIterator() -> CountableRange<T>.Iterator {
        return (0..<self).makeIterator()
    }
}
```